# How do I maximize points from loops?

Tags: runner2

Loops are one of the new obstacles in Runner 2. The game only mentions "Mash Space" (jump), and I've noticed that, while I've yet to fail a loop, I've gotten mixed point values from them.

*Some* of this I can attribute to entering the loop with a different bonus multiplier (i.e. Mega. vs. Extra), but the other part of the points seems random.

Is there some trick I'm not getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 4 possible "grades" per loop, which are earned based on the number of times you press "Jump" during them. The actual amount of points you gain is directly linked to the number of "Jump"s.

- 0-3 : Okay
- 4-6 : Good
- 7-9 : Awesome
- 10+ : Perfect! (Highest value I got was 5,580)

This was all done on the "Just Right" difficulty with no score multiplier, which may or may not alter the maximum (if that *is* the maximum) point value.

The bottom line is, when they say "Mash Jump", they mean it! Flex those spacebar muscles, kiddos!

Comment: For controller users, you rotate the right stick and try to keep Commander Video in light beam that appears. The longer you keep it on him, the higher your score. I haven't gotten over 15000 from it though, so I don't know what the maximum score is.

Comment: It took me far too long to figure out how to do this properly haha. I use a controller and the highest score I've gotten is at least 15'000 but it went by too fast for me to see if it was 15'000 exactly or if it'd be possible to get a higher score. If anyone knows what the highest score is for a loop I'd love to know.

Comment: Just confirming that 5,580 is the highest value you can get from loops, which then gets multiplied by your multiplier. At Extra, a perfect loop should net you 5 * 5,580 points, or 27,900.